# Fans and power lights don't turn off in standby

Tags: power-supply, sleep, fan

My desktop computer (Zotac 8200 motherboard) has a problem when I put it into standby mode. I use Windows 7 to put it into standby. The cpu fan, system fan, and PSU fan don't turn off. Nor does the power light in the front of the computer. I can't find any settings in the BIOS that all me to control this strange behavior. The computer can resume successfully from standby so it isn't froozen.
What can I do? Thanks

Comment: Standby is a low-power mode, but the computer may still need cooling. Hibernate is a power-off mode which allows relatively quick restart (not as quick as standby).

Comment: @Artelius - S3 standby does not need cooling. The CPU is powered off and its contents are stored in RAM. The only power used is to refresh the RAM

Answer (score 5):

In your BIOS you should look for something like Standby/Sleep State or Power state, and make sure that it says S3 and not S1, which will leave the CPU on, which will require cooling.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I found an ACPI setting in my BIOS which says: S1(POS) 
It doesn't let me change it to any other setting. Is that normal?
I just bought this motherboard, shouldn't it support S3?

Comment: If the BIOS doesnt support S3, I would check the manufacturer's site for a BIOS update. S1 is the reason nothing shuts off. It doesn't power off the CPU, so it can't safely turn the fans off.

Answer (score 1):

lol thanks for the evolving errors Microsoft. I just installed windows 8.1 on a fresh unaltered out of the box ssd's in raid0 setup and it wont shutdown. Or power down.

and by shutdown I mean  QUIET. no fans or blinky lights... this new feature called hibernate ha doesn't sound like it. as for sleep  if they meant shut off the monitor and keyboard / mouse lights. that works great. all these configurations can be implemented through our complicated options tabs via desktop gui or bios. but turn off the fans = hold down power button for 4+ seconds on all atx cases. DONE. magic... tools.

ps my x58 motherboard could use a s4 or perhaps a s6 version if pos and (s3) don't work :P