# How can I get Windows 7 to turn off lights?

Tags: windows-7

Since I installed Windows 7, the lights on thumb drives don't turn off when the option to eject them is selected.  Also, the lights on the power button and hard drive indicator lights on my case never go out when Windows is shut down.

Answer (score 4):

This is the default behavior since Vista. But you can fix it:

- run regedit.exe, go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\usbhub`,
- create a key with the name `HubG`
- create a DWORD32 with the name `DisableOnSoftRemove`
- change the Value data field to 1 and click OK

[image]

[image]

**(picture-)Source:**

http://www.howtogeek.com/120914/how-to-make-your-usb-devices-power-down-on-safe-removal-in-windows/

Comment: [this](http://superuser.com/questions/82190/fans-and-power-lights-dont-turn-off-in-standby) may also be relevant.